# Change color of HTML background ONLY

Tags: html, css, background, background-color

My body is 1024px wide. When I set background of the html tag in CSS to a color (say, maroon,) all of the page becomes maroon.

Normal behavior, but how do I set one color for body and another color for the space the body doesn't use?

When I set the background of body, only my first div is colored.

Comment: Set it on the `html`, `body` elements respectively. Generally though, the `body` element is the same size as the `html` element. There is just a `8px` margin by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that only your first div is colored is this: the `html` element takes up all visible space in the document, but the `body` takes up only as much space as its children.

Fix: set a fixed width and height for the body first, then use `background-color` on both the `body` and `html`.

```
body { background-color: white; } /* color for body */
html { background-color: maroon; } /* color for space not used by body */
```

Comment: I did that, but still the first div is the only one colored.

Comment: @Jonathan Did you set a fixed width and height?

Comment: I know that I can set the body background color in JavaScript using document.body.backgroundColor (or a myriad of syntax variations of that), but how can I set the html background color in JavaScript? I've got a test page that's doing that html css code, but I'd like to apply some logic to whether I set it at run time rather than it be hard-coded in CSS like that.

Comment: @Dee2000: `document.documentElement.backgroundColor`. The root `<html>` element can be accesed by [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement).

Answer (score 0):

In CSS/HTML every element receives many properties from its parent, if not specifically defined. When it comes to colors, most element will have a transparent background (or no background) unless you set its CSS properties.

Therefore, you need to set the properties accordingly:

```
html {background-color:#000;}
body {background-color:#fff;}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know that I can set the body background color in JavaScript using document.body.backgroundColor (or a myriad of syntax variations of that), but how can I set the html background color in JavaScript? I've got a test page that's doing that html css code, but I'd like to apply some logic to whether I set it at run time rather than it be hard-coded in CSS like that.

Comment: @Dee2000 use the `style` property of any DOM element i.e `document.body.style.background = #000;` or you can do it in jQuery with `$('#mydiv').css('background-color','#000')`

Comment: Yes, but how do I change the background color of "html" like you have in your CSS code snippet "html { background-color:#000; }